# Completely positive non-increasing linear map imply non-increasing on hermitian operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-information

Let $T$ be a completely positive linear map from $L(H)$ to $L(H)$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space.
We have that
$$T(X) = \sum_i A_iXA_i^\dagger$$
where $\{A_i\}_i$ are the Kraus operators, and we know that $\sum_iA_iA_i^\dagger \leq I$, with $I$ the identity.

Can we deduce from this that for $X\in L(H)$ such that $X = X^\dagger$ and $X\geq 0$ then $T(X) \leq X$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, take e.g. $X=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $A_0=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ (only one $A_i$).